# Covariance of two variables hat check

Tags: probability, combinatorics, random-variables, expectation, covariance

I can't do this, I give up. I am just not able to do it. I don't know what is wrong with me but I can't do it and I need help.

Hat check experiment with 3 hats, outcomes 1,2,3|1,3,2|2,1,3|3,2,1 have probability of 1/5, rest are 1/10

I want to find the covariance of $X_1$ = person 1 gets their hat and Y = number of people that get their hat.

So I need to find the E(X,Y) which is a cross product multiplication of all the possibilites of the outcomes of both experiments combines. Ok so there are only two outcomes I need to look at for $X_1$ and both have probability of 1/5. There are two outcomes for N, 3 with probabiliy 1/5 and 1 with probability 3/5.

This gives me $2/5 * 3/5 + 3/5* 2/5$

This gives me 12/25

So plug in this mindless formula

$12/25 - E(X_1)E(Y)$

I know that $E(X_1) = 2/5$

$E(Y) = 6/5$

That is 12/25 so my covariance is zero but this is wrong. Where did I go wrong. Oh lawd jesus someone save me before I go insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try making a table of the events as well a their corresponding outcomes and probabilities.  Then define Z = X*Y and find the expected value of Z.

```
outcome | X | Y |  P  |  Z |

1,2,3     1   3   1/5    3
1,3,2     1   1   1/5    1
etc.
```

I sincerely hope that my answer made it in time before you went insane!

Comment: I did that and I still get the incorrect answer.

Comment: @PaulthePirate  What did you get for E(Z) doing it this way?

Comment: 12/25 is what I got

Comment: @PaulthePirate For all the other outcomes, X*Y=0, right?

Comment: Yes, there are only two outcomes to count for Y and 1 for X so I only have 2 outcomes in Z to count.

Comment: @PaulthePirate I only see three possible outcomes for Z, 3,1, and 0.  What is P(Z=3)?  What is P(Z=1)?

Comment: Ahhh I got it, I was doing some weird cross product thing. I thought I was doing the table right but I wasn't so I just find the probability by finding the chance that aspecific item has and then multiply it by the value.

Comment: @PaulthePirate Exactly, glad I could help!